# Era formatted as 'n.e.' by DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

When I create the formatter for the era:

```
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.*

var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("G");
```

and then use it I get **n.e.** instead for example  **AD**.

```
formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()); //n.e.
```

Why is era formatted as **n.e**?

I'm using java 11 on ubuntu bionic:

```
openjdk 11 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What is your system locale including language and country? Can you please print `Locale.getDefault()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your default locale is **Polish**. I have two reasons to assume that:

a) Your name sounds like Polish so you might work on a computer located in Poland. Is my speculation right?

b) In Polish: The era AD is indeed formatted as "n.e.". This abbreviation stands for "naszej ery" (= current era).

Whatever your locale might really be, I don't see any bug. If you insist on "AD" then please change the locale appropriately by passing it as extra parameter to `DateTimeFormatter`-factory method. If you don't find such a locale then you might also consider using the builder approach and use:

```
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0, "BC");
map.put(1, "AD");
DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendText(ChronoField.ERA, map).toFormatter();
```

Comment: Yep! You are right. Just a small note: formatter has support for locale, withLocale method. `var formatterIso = formatter.withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);` formats era as 'AD'

Comment: I think `Locale.ROOT` should be used here instead,  since it is regarded as the neutral locale.